# Using "With" SQL on Oracle 10g causing errors

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, common-table-expression

First ill tell you what the logic in my code is, after my last post it was pointed out to me that my procedure was inefficient and that i should think about logic of my approach..

To put it simply, i want to join a bunch of tables and filter them out to reflect a certain scheme, the process in "Z" in the bellow code

And then parse through that data using y on z...

Looking at the examples online i cant see why this code dosnt work, i have read in a few places that it may be a oracle 10g issue but note sure.. any recommendations would be great

The error i get is "ORA-00904: "Z"."COMMENTS": invalid identifier"

```
with 
z as 
(
Select * 
 FROM 
 (
    iacd_note c
    inner join iacd_ncr_note e on C.NOTE_ID=E.NOTE_ID
    inner join iacd_ncr f on E.NCR_ID=F.NCR_ID
    inner join iacd_ncr_iac g on F.NCR_ID=G.NCR_ID  
 )
 WHERE c.create_date >= date'2014-01-01'
    AND c.create_date < date'2014-12-31' 
    AND G.SCHEME_ID in (36,37,38,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,39,40,44,42,43,45, 48,49,50,51,52,55,56,57,58,68,69,70,71)
),
y as 
(
Select *
From iacd_asset
)

SELECT y.bridge_no, COUNT(*) AS comment_cnt
  FROM y INNER JOIN z
    ON REGEXP_LIKE(z.comments, '(^|\W)BN' || y.bridge_no || '(\W|$)', 'i')
 GROUP BY y.bridge_no
 ORDER BY comment_cnt;
```

Z.COMMENTS should be part of the merges happening in z

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Sorry that was stupid of me to leave out, added to main post

Comment: Should `b.bridge_no` be `y.bridge_no` (in the group by)

Comment: Your right, changed that, now get a different error.. main post updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the output of a with clause may not have the same column names as the original tables, so i selected all of z and noticed there was an odd automated name for the row i was after...

Comment: Well, that's not true - a `with` clause, like any subquery, does not have to rename every column from the original tables.

Answer (score 0):

This subquery is invalid SQL syntax:

```
Select * 
FROM 
(
   iacd_note c
   inner join iacd_ncr_note e on C.NOTE_ID=E.NOTE_ID
   inner join iacd_ncr f on E.NCR_ID=F.NCR_ID
   inner join iacd_ncr_iac g on F.NCR_ID=G.NCR_ID  
)
WHERE ...
```

You can't put parentheses around the FROM clause. Instead:

```
Select * 
FROM iacd_note c
inner join iacd_ncr_note e on C.NOTE_ID=E.NOTE_ID
inner join iacd_ncr f on E.NCR_ID=F.NCR_ID
inner join iacd_ncr_iac g on F.NCR_ID=G.NCR_ID  
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Hi Removed the brackets.. still get "ORA-00904: "Z"."COMMENTS": invalid identifier"    .. is the way im referencing the output of Z wrong?